# Does disabling a USB port stop power from being provided on pins 1/4?

Tags: usb, electrical-power

This is hopefully a simple question. When you disable a USB port at the BIOS level, or if it is disabled by group policy/at the OS level, does it still provide the +5VDC power on pin 1? I ask because of an amusing issue where a coworker tried charging his cell phone using a USB cable off of the front bezel while he was in the datacenter. I haven't really been able to find the answer as to whether or not the disabled port will still provide power on pin 1 or not.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the manufacturer's implementation. The only way you are going to know for your server is to test it.

Comment: Shorting the pins across a voltage detector seems reasonable...

Answer (score 1):

In our restricted system, USB-ports on clients are disabled for USB-storage devices through GPO, and they still provide power. Actually, it's more of a hack, making vital driver-files inaccessible to users ("Device was not installed properly..."). Thus we can still allow mice and other devices. If it's the same in the BIOS, it's pretty much individual from model to model.